# Error:Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I update my android studio and restart it, it works properly but when i try to imoprt my previous project it shows error somthing like that:

here is the snapshot of error...

[Error during import the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AynD4.png)

and here is my gradle file...

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Are you using offline mode?

Comment: no its not on offline mode

Comment: Try to check this link in the same machine: https://bintray.com/artifact/download/android/android-tools/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.1.0-alpha1/gradle-2.1.0-alpha1.pom

Comment: This is not working...

Comment: It means that your machine is not able to get the plugin file. It is not an Android Studio or gradle issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with other distribution of gradle.

Open `gradle-wrapper.properties`which It's inside `gradle/wrapper` folder and in `distributionUrl` set another one which work, for example:

```
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

**EDIT**

Try with this classpath in global `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Comment: i have recent one  " https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip "    and i didn't find any which is recent except this,but its not working

Comment: Did you try with a lower version?

Comment: yes, i've try old ones and new ones not working at all

Comment: Could you post your global build.gradle?

Comment: yeah sure, why not

Comment: Try cleanning the project and building again in build menu option, looks like is not getting the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today, and when I updated the Android Plugin Version to the recent one, it worked. So, I think when you meet this problem, you can update the Gradle and Android Plugin Version to the newest. It always works. This is my configuration:

[image: This is my configuration]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem upgrading my Android Studio to 2.2.0. I changed the classpath property of my build.gradle file but the difference with the answers above is that I didn't put the version of the Gradle but the Android Studio's one and it worked. Note that you also need to verify the Ggradle home path in `file>>settings>>build,execution,deployment>>gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
```